# Azure BLOB Download is very slow\inconsistent from a Linux Host (CentOS 7)

Tags: linux, centos, azure, blob-storage

I was getting reports that "downloads from Azure are slow" from one of our datacenters, so to recreate I've hosted my own BLOB storage and gave it a go.  All hosts are in the same subnet, same switch, same /24.  There is no appreciable network gear inbetween, just hosts with a public IP on a switch with a grossly overspec'd router.  I've tried two ISPs, same results.  I've tried other datacenters, similar results.  The BLOB is nothing special.  It's a 5G test.bin file.

In short I'm getting wild swings in download speed, even dead at night when there's guaranteed to be no traffic on the links (yes I've verified).  The test was to wget my test.bin file (https), wait 20 seconds, and chart speed.

```
Host1 - 800 KB/s
Host2 - 900 KB/s
Host3 - 900 KB/s
Host4 - 2.5 MB/s
Host5 - 900 KB/s
Host6 - 46.5 MB/s
Host7 - 45 MB/s
Host8 - 42.7 MB/s
Host9 - 45 MB/s
Host10 - 47 MB/s
Host 11 - 47.3MB/s
Host 11 Guest 1 -  396KB/s
Host 11 Guest 2 - 426KB/s"
Host 12 - 4.71MB/s
Host 12 Guest 1 - 421KB/s"
Host 13 - 2 MB/s
Host 14 - 45.1MB/s
Host 14 Guest 1 - 386KB/s"
Host 15 - 47.6MB/s
Host 15 Gest 1 - 452KB/s"
Host 16 - 2.51MB/s
Host 16 guest 1 - 398KB/s
Host 16 guest 2 - 505KB/s"
```

Factors eliminated

- Not the ISP.  I tried both.  Both can't be bad.  Other regions have similar swings.  These hosts all have either 1G or 10G interfaces, get full line rate on speedtest, and download other files at appreciable speeds.
- Not IP throttling.  I've put "fast host IPs" on "slow hosts" and the fastness or slowness stayed with the machine.
- I don't think it's the path per se.  It's too consistent and does not follow source IP.  Also some 'fast hosts' have the same traceroutes as 'slow hosts'.  Slow are always slow, fast are always fast.
- Booting into various distros, particularly CentOS8, seemed to speed things up in some occasions.  Switched back, everything went slow again.
- This is like clockwork.  Speeds will par down do what I post here no matter if I try at 12:00 AM local time.
- Downloading from a VM in the same region is considerably more consistent (not shown above.  The above is blob storage downloads)

I personally think this is some form of odd TCP congestion control thing that MS is doing.  I've seen that altering window sizes seemed to make some of the slower hosts a lot faster.  Sometimes the hosts will ramp up to around 45 Mbps, sit there for 10 sec or so, then start dying down and settling at their eventual speed.

Any thoughts, I'm at a loss.

OS is CentOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful with some tips:
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-performance-checklist

https://www.azurespeed.com/Azure/Download

Comment: Link-only answers are not the right approach. You should include the gist into your answers, as the link aren't guaranteed to be there forever.

Answer (score 0):

Try AzCopy should be the fastest method to download your files.

reference: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It actually ended up being tuning settings on the linux host. GRO....